# My plist is not updated when i close my application and open it again

Tags: ios, uitableview, plist

Please, 
I created a plist with some Keys and values,
And then  I tried to add new item to my `Plist` and save it.
After that i close my App and open it again, but i don't see my new items on my Table View.
So I don't understand where is my wrong !!!

Please Help!!!

```
NSArray *paths =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingString:@"MyProfile.plist"];
NSString *error=nil;
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:MyProfile format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

if (plistData){
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Error in save Data:%@",error);

}
```

Comment: Check if `[plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];` returns YES.

Comment: Thanks sir for your answer. Yes it is return Yes, and i tried ti use the console to print the contents of my plist, and it is updated with the new items, But When i tried to run my App on my iPhone, my plist is empty. And there is no item on my tableView. Plus when i add new items ,my App is crashed. Please Help!!!

Comment: I have some questions, if you post the relevant code it will helps a lot.First question: You load the plist file from document directory, but when did you save it. Second: How do you load the plist and construct a `NSArray`(I know that because you say "there is no item on my tableView", so you must use NSArray to provide the data of tableview).  Third: When app crashes, there should be some message, what is it with you.

Comment: In my Detail View , I have the following :- (void)viewDidLoad
{

self.filePathPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Profile" ofType:@"plist"];
    
    self.ProfileInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:self.filePathPlist];     self.namesProfile = [self.ProfileInfo objectForKey:@"Names"];
   
    
}

Comment: - (IBAction)saveDog:(id)sender {[self.namesProfile addObject:self.profileName.text];                                // Step: Set data in dictionary
    
 [self.ProfileInfo setValue:self.namesProfileDogs forKey: @"Names"];
    BOOL didWriteToFile = [self.ProfileInfo writeToFile:self.filePathPlist atomically:YES];
    
    
    if (didWriteToFile)
        
    {
        
        NSLog(@"Write to .plist file is a SUCCESS!");
        
    }
    
    else
        
    {
      NSLog(@"Write to .plist file is a FAILURE!");
}}

Comment: My problem now is when i update my Plist then it working fine on my simulator. But when when i  Run my App , and if i added new items to my list , then my view table is not Updated. and the another issue, when i close my App and open it again , My APP is not updated.

Comment: What is your list ? Is it self.ProfileInfo ? Is self.ProfileInfo is mutable ?

Comment: is my comment clear for you ? Or if you want , i can send you my code !!!

Comment: Ok, cangmuma@gmail.com

Comment: Well I have not got your email yet...

Comment: `self.names = [self.profileInfo objectForKey:@"Names"];` self.names here is a NSArray instance, not a NSMutableArray, so you can't send `addObject:` method to it.

Comment: Thanks, But I don't get any error when i run the App .

Comment: self.names is :@property (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *names; so there is no problem with it.

Comment: You declare it as `NSMutableArray` does not means it is a `NSMutableArray`, you can `NSLog(@"%@", [self.names class])` to check its class.

Comment: Thanks sir for your feedback. I got the following :__NSCFArray

Comment: I don't understand, how can i fix this issue ? Please Help1!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.profileInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePathPlist];`

The values in `self.profileInfo` is not mutable, if the value for a specific key is a array, it will be `NSArray` not `NSMutableArray`.

Let's talk about the code below:

`self.names = [self.profileInfo objectForKey:@"Names"];`

Although you declare the property `names` as a `NSMutableArray`, the instance you get here is still a `NSArray`. So you should send mutableCopy method to id to get a mutable array:

`self.names = [[self.profileInfo objectForKey:@"Names"] mutableCopy];`

BTW:

You can also save `self.profileInfo` to file directly using `[self.profileInfo writeToFile:path atomically:YES]`.